# Command Binding with MVVM

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, mvvm, windows-phone-8, observablecollection

My WP7 application allows users to answer to questions made by others.
The problem is how to list them under the question: at the moment I used MVVM method and they are all part of an ObservableCollection with is associated to a LongListSelector.

```
<toolkit:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IsFlatList="True">

                            <toolkit:LongListSelector.DataContext>
                                <local:ResponsesViewModel/>
                            </toolkit:LongListSelector.DataContext>
                            <toolkit:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <local:BoxRisposta />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </toolkit:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>                            
                         </toolkit:LongListSelector>
```

Each item is bound in a custom user control called `BoxRisposta`, that cointains textboxes to display the username, the time at which the user replied,a RichTextBox that cointains the reply.

The list of responses is part of this ViewModel class.

```
Public Class ResponsesViewModel
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private _Items As ObservableCollection(Of Risposta)
    Public Property Items() As ObservableCollection(Of Risposta)
        Get
            Return _Items
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of Risposta))
            _Items = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        Me.Items = New ObservableCollection(Of Risposta)()
        QuoteCommand = New ActionCommand(New Action(Of Object)(Sub(p)
                                                                   MessageBox.Show("quoted")
                                                               End Sub))
    End Sub

    Private _QuoteCommand As ICommand
    Public Property QuoteCommand As ICommand
        Get
            Return _QuoteCommand
        End Get
        Private Set(value As ICommand)
            _QuoteCommand = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyName As String)
        Dim handler As PropertyChangedEventHandler = PropertyChangedEvent
        If handler IsNot Nothing Then
            handler(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class ActionCommand
    Implements ICommand
    Private execAction As Action(Of Object)
    Private canExecFunc As Func(Of Object, Boolean)

    Public Sub New(execAction As Action(Of Object))
        Me.execAction = execAction
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(execAction As Action(Of Object), canExecFunc As Func(Of Object, Boolean))
        Me.execAction = execAction
        Me.canExecFunc = canExecFunc
    End Sub

    Public Function CanExecute(parameter As Object) As Boolean Implements ICommand.CanExecute
        If canExecFunc IsNot Nothing Then
            Return canExecFunc.Invoke(parameter)
        Else
            Return True
        End If
    End Function

    Public Event CanExecuteChanged As System.EventHandler Implements ICommand.CanExecuteChanged

    Public Sub Execute(parameter As Object) Implements ICommand.Execute
        If execAction IsNot Nothing Then
            execAction.Invoke(parameter)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Do you see that I added a Command inside it? I would like to add a button inside my custom user control thst works as "quote button" and tells to ViewModel class that a response is being quoted and also pass the content of that response.

I'm stuck here, I don't kwnow how to bind a command in this specific case where I have a list of items, not just one object (as most part of examples on internet show)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to pass DataContext of parent LLS:

```
<toolkit:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <local:BoxRisposta QuoteCommand="{Binding ElementName=ResponseList,
                               Path=DataContext.QuoteCommand}" DeleteCommand="{Binding ElementName=ResponseList,
                               Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
</toolkit:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 <local:BoxRisposta  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"/>
```

Now your user control uses the same datacontext your current page

Comment: Not this, I can't override DataContext which is already set with the class containing response infos.